# Raphael.js - How to programmatically generate element name?

Tags: raphael, element

I have a number of Raphael rectangle elements hard-coded into the page via php, which generates them on the fly depending on how many are needed when the page is called.

What I'm trying to do is write a javascript function that will take an id number and alter the relevant Raphael function's background color.

I know the below example won't work, but this is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
var rectangle_1 = paper.rect(100, 10, 200, 75);
var rectangle_2 = paper.rect(400, 10, 200, 75);
var rectangle_3 = paper.rect(700, 10, 200, 75);

change_color('1');

function change_color(id) {
  variable_name = 'rectangle_' + id;
  variable_name.attr({fill: 'blue', stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 3});
}
```

Clearly this doesn't work and any help and advice on how to generate an element name on the fly would be greatly appreciated,

regards,

Ste

Answer (score 0):

Just use an array or an object to store the rects instead of named variables.

```
var rectangles = [];
rectangles[0] = paper.rect(100, 10, 200, 75);
rectangles[1] = paper.rect(400, 10, 200, 75);
rectangles[2] = paper.rect(700, 10, 200, 75);

change_color(1);

function change_color(id) {
  rectangles[id].attr({fill: 'blue', stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 3});
}
```

If you need string IDs, you can do it as an object:

```
var rectangles = {};
rectangles['one'] = ...
```